# Size of class - C++

Tags: c++, function, virtual, sizeof

I have the following code about object sizes:

```
class A 
{ 
public: 
    int _i; 
    virtual int getI () = 0; 
    int setI (int i); 
}; 
class B : public A 
{ 
public: 
    int getI (); 
    virtual int setI (int i); 
}; 

class C : public B 
{ 
public: 
    int _i; 
    int getI (); 
    int setI (int i); 
}; 

int main () 
{ 
    B b; 
    C c; 
}
```

Why the size of 
    C c;
is 12? What parts included in the size calculation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7453269/922184

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof(int A::_i) + sizeof(int C::_i) + sizeof(pointer to virtual table)`

The size of all these parts is implementation-dependent, in your case, each one has size 4.

Comment: Why do I have sizeof virtual table? What virtual function?

Comment: @gfjhgrjrerjhm: Virtual functions are functions with the `virtual` keyword. Look at your code and search for that keyword to answer "What virtual function?"

Comment: @MikeSeymour So by what you say - I have two virtual functions, so the final calculation will be 16... 2 virtual and 2 ints

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm: There will be a single virtual function table for the *class*; the one for `C` will contain two function pointers. Each *object* will contain a pointer to that table - just one pointer, however many virtual functions there are. (Of course this is all compiler dependent, but that's how all compilers do it.)

Comment: @rve Can you please explain me about this specific problem?

Comment: @fgf... have a look here as well (this article contains example of memory layout that includes vptr): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: You have virtual method `A::getI` which is inherited by `B` and `C`, and another one `B::setI` is introduced in B and inherited by C. Your compiler implements virtual methods by creating a virtual method table for each type.

Answer (score 5):

The size of just about any class is implementation dependent, but I'll
guess that you're on a 32 bit machine, and class C contains a 4 byte
`vptr` and two four byte `int` (`A::_i` and `C::_i`).

Comment: The pointer to the `vtbl`.  It's additional information the compiler inserts into the object to help in dynamic resolution of virtual function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the object will be platform specific. For example on a 64 bit platform I would expect the size to be 24 bytes. What constitutes the size of an object is a bit tricky. It is made up from variety of components:

- The obvious components of the size are the data members: in your case you got two `int` somewhere in the hierarchy, i.e. this will contribute `2 * sizeof(int)`.
- The well-known hidden component is a pointer to the "vtable", i.e. a pointer to some sort of data structure which deals with the ways virtual functions are called. This will generally contribute a pointer size.
- Probably entirely ignored by most are the hidden pointers coming with the multiple inheritance especially when the object involves a virtual base class: to make the object look as if it is one in specific hierarchy it will include more than on "vtable" pointer.
- More known although ignored by many is "padding" i.e. hidden bytes used to assure that data members are aligned to addresses preferred by the CPU. In general, the preferred alignment is roughly the size of the type up to the size of a cache line on the given system if there are corresponding fundamental types of this size. That is, typically the maximum alignment is 16 bytes.
- Finally, I can think of a fun one with empty classes: since subobjects need to have distinct addresses, each empty class will by treated as if it is at least one byte big unless the empty class is a base class in which case it may share the same address as other bases.

Most of the hidden stuff doesn't apply but for you class you have `2 * sizeof(int) + sizeof(T*)` for a suitable type used to access the virtual function table.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `C c;` is actually implementation defined. If you have any code that actually relies on the size, this code is horribly wrong and may break whenever the compiler is switched.

Now to your actuall questions: You probably either thought `C` would have the size of the  `int` contained in `C` or alternatively you would have thought it to have the size of the `int` from `C` plus the one from `A`.

Both these guesses are wrong for two reasons:

- There might be so called padding in your structures. Sometimes types need to be aligned to certain boundaries. In order to enforce these alignments, the compiler introduces some area of "wasted" space between your fields to keep them at these places. You can never rely on the amount of this padding.
- There is another point, and I mainly think your teacher wanted to show you this: If you write `c.getI()` the computer has to know which method to call, i.e. whether to call the one from `A`, `B` or `C`. This information needs to be stored somewhere. The storage for this information adds some additional size to your struct, but you can never rely on how much will be added. Some people might try to tell you that this is only stored by using one pointer, but this is **not correct**. The compiler is allowed to use as much space to store this information as it likes. Most compiler only do use one pointer for efficiency reasons, but if you rely on this, your code will be wrong for compilers which do handle this differently.

If you want to know more, just google for "virtual method invocation", and you can find some examples for common implementations for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use 32 bit compiler. 
This is the memory layout of class C:

```
class C size(12):
    +---
    | +--- (base class B)
    | | +--- (base class A)
 0  | | | {vfptr}
 4  | | | _i
    | | +---
    | +---
 8  | _i
    +---

C::$vftable@:
    | &C_meta
    |  0
 0  | &C::getI
 1  | &C::setI
```

Based on it, you can see which parts conduct to size of class.

You can read more about virtual function, virtual inheritance, virtual table to figure out the way that they are organized and contributed to class size.

If you use MVSC, you can use -d1reportAllClassLayout option when you compile to see the layout of your class.